# can we work with Django authentication without builtin Django forms

Tags: python, django

I want to use input field for authentication but if I search for authentication tutorial they are using built-in Django forms which I can't design it using html

Comment: See stackoverflow guidelines. Show some code or error which you are getting otherwise your question will be down voting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) how forms are rendered or you can pretty much write any HTML that you want just make sure your input name attributes match whatever you are accepting on backend.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Bootstrap 4 for styling. Start out by creating a view that subclasses [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView). In the html file, instead of using `{{ form }}` or `{{ form.username }}` & `{{ form.password }}`, you can supply your own html for the fields. Just make sure your inputs are named the same as in `{{ form }}`.

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
```

login.html:

```
{% block content %}
...
<div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
        <div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">
            <form id="login-form" class="form" action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="text-white">Username:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="text-white">Password:</label><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-light btn-md btn-block mt-5"
                           value="log in">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
{% endblock content %}
```